# How to unlock my windows phone's screen

Tags: lock-screen, pin, battery-saver

In use a Microsoft Lumia 540. Unfortunately, I turned on the battery saver. Now I cannot use my pin to unlock the phone. What do I do.

Comment: Battery saver has nothing to do with this. What happens when you try to unlock your phone.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Normally, no. But without knowing the OS we can't really say that; if he's running the Insider Preview that can definitely do weird things.

Comment: @RareNCool Battery saver option can be turned on/off via quick actions without unlocking the phone. I seriously doubt it is causing the issue. But you could be right. So let's wait till we hear from the OP.